# How to create a "Denoising Autoencoder" in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, autoencoder

I know Matlab has the function `TrainAutoencoder(input, settings)` to create and train an autoencoder. The result is capable of running the two functions of "**Encode**" and "**Decode**".
But this is only applicable to the case of normal autoencoders. What if you want to have a **denoising autoencoder**? I searched and found some sample codes, where they used the "Network" function to convert the autoencoder to a normal network and then `Train(network, noisyInput, smoothOutput)`like a denoising autoencoder.

But there are multiple missing parts:

1. How to use this new network object to "encode" new data points? it doesn't support the encode().
2. How to get the "latent" variables to the features, out of this "network'?

I appreciate if anyone could help me resolve this issue.
Thanks,
-Moein

Answer (score 1):

1. At present (2019a), MATALAB does not permit users to add layers manually in autoencoder. If you want to build up your own, you will have start from the scratch by using layers provided by MATLAB;
2. In order to to use TrainNetwork(...) to train your model, you will have you find out a way to insert your data into an object called imDatastore. The difficulty for autoencoder's data is that there is NO label, which is required by imDatastore, hence you will have to find out a smart way to avoid it--essentially you are to deal with a so-called OCC (One Class Classification) problem.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.datastore.imagedatastore.html

3. Use activations(...) to dump outputs from intermediate (hidden) layers

https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/activations.html?searchHighlight=activations&s_tid=doc_srchtitle

4. I swang between using MATLAB and Python (Keras) for deep learning for a couple of weeks, eventually I chose the latter, albeit I am a long-term and loyal user to MATLAB and a rookie to Python. My two cents are that there are too many restrictions in the former regarding deep learning.

Good luck.:-)

Comment: Thank you so much Theron, 
I actually was able to create a multilayer feedforward net which resembles the autoencoder structure. Now, the question is: is there any way to simulate the "encode" process only on the first half of the layers?

Answer (score 0):

If you 'simulation' means prediction/inference, simply use activations(...) to dump outputs from any intermediate (hidden) layers as I mentioned earlier so that you can check them.

Another way is that you construct an identical network but with the encoding part only, copy your trained parameters into it, and feed your simulated signals.